# Heroku new API for Release doesn't have commit hash

Tags: api, heroku

The question is about the new heroku API structure:

"Accept":"application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"

If I asked for the release data I get that one:

```
{
"app":{"id":"b3d70761-ee7f-4039-91ac-402d2f9d12b6","name":"some-name"},
"created_at":"2015-03-22T07:33:18Z",
"description":"Set COMMIT_HASH config vars",
"id":"610f896a-3f34-44af-b39a-43070f02891f",
"slug":{"id":"2e8e024d-4ffa-44ff-8da9-5accd3874a5e"},"updated_at":"2015-03-22T07:33:18Z",
"user":{"email":"tmp@mail.com","id":"7d46e391-63ca-4b19-b4e4-96fec8487f77"},
"version":507
}
```

The only problem here is that there is no
git commit hash , which does exist in the old
structure. Which looks like that:

```
"addons": [
    "newrelic:stark",
    "rediscloud:100",
    "redistogo:nano",
    "deployhooks:http"
],
"commit": "9a627af", <<===
"created_at": "2015/03/18 11:52:58 -0700",
"descr": "Deploy 9a627af",
"env": {
},
"name": "v461",
"pstable": {
    "web": "java -Dkeyvalue.datasource=redis $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/some.jar --server.port=$PORT"
},
"user": "tmp@tmp.com"
```

So for now I have to use both structures
and eventually 2 versions of the same api: 
Any ideas for any alternative ?

Thanks in advance
Roman

Comment: I'm sure you didn't mean to but you've just published the credentials to connect to all your database on the internet... I seriously recommend you go and change all usernames and passwords immediately.

Comment: It's  a test net but thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the API now returns a Slug for a Release, and you can look up that Slug for the commit.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#slug